# HTML & JS Markup - better way possible?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm loading my html files into a #content div in order to avoid the complete page to reload when clicking on a link. I'm doing this by calling the following in my index.html:

```
[...]
<div id="content">

    <script type="text/javascript">$("#content").load("home.html");</script>

</div>
```

The problem is that no javascript in my global.js will be executed if it's related to one of the html files that will be loaded into my #content div.

In order to handle that fact I simply put the js of the related html file right into that specific one by posting it with the `<script>` command, e.g. like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".faq").click(function () {
        $(this).find(".faq_answer").toggle();
    });
});

</script>
```

I'm totally unhappy with it and so my question is: **is there a way I could put my js back in my global.js file?**

Comment: Learn about event delegation: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/.

Comment: If all you need is event handling, event delegation is great. If you have other scripts to run only when navigating to different "pages", you should read more about routing, history and probably require.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correclty your question, you need to use even delegation to assign event handlers to elements that doesn't exist yet

```
$(document).on("click",".faq", function (){ ... })
```

Where `document` can be replaced by any container of `.faq` that exists at bind time.

For more details check "Direct and delegated" section [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Thank you very much, that did solve the problem. I didnt know event delegation before, always good to learn something new!

Answer (score 0):

Try to load the page through your global.js inside of keeping it in your html page.
Keep the script that will load the content first.
This should work